# Function pointers with differing return types in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I'm going through the fun process of porting an ActionScript project over to C#.  One of the interesting features I've found is the very relaxed type checking in ActionScript.

As an example -

```
table = new Dictionary();
table["id1"]    = func1;
table["id2"]    = func2;
table["id3"]    = func3;
table["id4"]    = func4;
```

Where func1, func2, func3 and func4 all have the same parameter types but some of them return void and some return object types is totally acceptable in ActionScript.

I was going to tackle this using delegates until I realised they had differing return types.

Is there a clean way to handle this in C# without refactoring and, if so, what is it?

[EDIT] I'm not condoning the way the original code was written.  It checks the id of the function and processes differently depending on what it expects to be returned (or to not be returned).  I could refactor this but would rather port the project across as a whole and then work on structure improvements.

[EDIT] The code I'm porting is a computer language parser (interpreter not compiler). It uses the computer keywords as the keys into the table's dictionary, calling the appropriate functions to carry out those commands. Some commands return void because they just perform processing. Some return values (such as GetVar functions).

Comment: Well what do you expect this to do?  What do you expect to happen when you call a method, when you don't even know if it has a return value, or what type it might be if it does?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it'll be much easier to help you.

Comment: What type do you want to use for each entry? You could wrap them in a `Func<T1, ..., TN, object>` and return `null` for wrapped `Action`s.

Comment: How can you assign a value to a table that returns nothing?  Why not just func3;

Comment: It's a look up table for a language parser (interpreter not compiler). Some commands return a value and others perform processing without returning anything. I didn't write the original code but I'm tasked with porting it to C#

Comment: Broadly, you would need to use the `Delegate` base class as the value type for your dictionary. See marked duplicate for details. Of course, to make use of this later, you'll have to do some casting, but that's inevitable. It's not going to be possible to use a return value from an invocation without at _some_ point knowing the type of that value (unless all you care about is calling `object.ToString()`, which all objects have).